# Microsoft graph API - Unable to move email with error 415

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph API to move email between inbox folders.

We per manual on `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http`
I'm trying to run a POST call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userID}/messages/{messageID}/move`

But all I get is error 415 Unsupported Media Type

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBodyRead",
        "message": "A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaTyp...' matches the content type 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------951291014204912961424386'."
    }
}
```

I can't figure it out. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error I think is pointing out to the request body [Request Body][1]

[1]: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserID%7D/messages/%7BmessageID%7D/move Can you please check have you added in request body [request body reference][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWVgv.png DestinationId is Inbox

Answer (score 0):

I was using Postman and forgot to disable original Content-type which generated the error